# Pinch-zoom an image but starting zoomed out

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm writing Pinch/Zoom into my application, I have it working pretty good but am running into a problem or two.  First, I want the image to start off, fully zoomed out.  Where you see the whole image.  Second, I want the application to stop zooming out when it reaches that point.  So you can keep pinching/panning but it doesn't continue to calculate.  Thanks in advance for you help.  See below for the code.

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\", "*.jpg");
        MainImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(files[0]));
}

 private void Image_ManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ManipulationContainer = ScrollViewerParent;
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void Image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        int nrOfPoints = 0;

        lock (mutex)
        {
            nrOfPoints = nrOfTouchPoints;
        }

        if (nrOfPoints >= 2)
        {                
            var matrix = MainImage.LayoutTransform.Value;

            Point? centerOfPinch = (e.ManipulationContainer as FrameworkElement)?.TranslatePoint(e.ManipulationOrigin, ScrollViewerParent);

            if (centerOfPinch == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var deltaManipulation = e.DeltaManipulation;
            matrix.ScaleAt(deltaManipulation.Scale.X, deltaManipulation.Scale.Y, centerOfPinch.Value.X, centerOfPinch.Value.Y);
            MainImage.LayoutTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);

            Point? originOfManipulation = (e.ManipulationContainer as FrameworkElement)?.TranslatePoint(e.ManipulationOrigin, MainImage);

            double scrollViewerOffsetX = ScrollViewerParent.HorizontalOffset;
            double scrollViewerOffsetY = ScrollViewerParent.VerticalOffset;

            double pointMovedOnXOffset = originOfManipulation.Value.X - originOfManipulation.Value.X * deltaManipulation.Scale.X;
            double pointMovedOnYOffset = originOfManipulation.Value.Y - originOfManipulation.Value.Y * deltaManipulation.Scale.Y;

            double multiplicatorX = ScrollViewerParent.ExtentWidth / MainImage.ActualWidth;
            double multiplicatorY = ScrollViewerParent.ExtentHeight / MainImage.ActualHeight;

            ScrollViewerParent.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scrollViewerOffsetX - pointMovedOnXOffset * multiplicatorX);
            ScrollViewerParent.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewerOffsetY - pointMovedOnYOffset * multiplicatorY);

            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ScrollViewerParent.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(ScrollViewerParent.HorizontalOffset - e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X);
            ScrollViewerParent.ScrollToVerticalOffset(ScrollViewerParent.VerticalOffset - e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y);
        }
    }

    private void MainImage_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (mutex)
        {
            nrOfTouchPoints++;
        }
    }

    private void MainImage_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (mutex)
        {
            nrOfTouchPoints--;
        }
    }

<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
        x:Name="ScrollViewerParent"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        PanningMode="Both">
        <Image MouseDown="MainImage_MouseDown"
            x:Name="MainImage"

            IsManipulationEnabled="True"
            TouchDown="MainImage_TouchDown"
            TouchUp="MainImage_TouchUp"
            ManipulationDelta="Image_ManipulationDelta"
            ManipulationStarting="Image_ManipulationStarting"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```